# Sharing resource groups on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to share a resource group in Microsoft Azure, but the users I give ownership/admin privileges can't see the resources or resource group within their Azure portal (I grant permissions on the resource group). Am I missing something in granting permissions? I checked that both users are admins in the active directory too, but I'm not entirely sure if that matters.

The resource group only contains a simple WebApp, Gateway and associated SQL server/database. The main Azure account and the other azure account are both under the same Azure subscription (BizSpark).

I am new to Azure, so thanks for any help!

Comment: From your description, it looks like you're doing the things correctly. Will it be possible for you to share a screenshot of permissions screen for the resource group?

Comment: Make sure the other users have selected your directory from the dropdown in the top-right corner of the portal.

Comment: Thanks BenV, that worked. I completely missed that option!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was being silly and didn't change directories. Thanks [BenV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310446/benv)!

> Make sure the other users have selected your directory from the drop-down in the top-right corner of the portal. – [BenV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310446/benv)